# I can't have more than one working command block in my Minecraft world

Tags: minecraft-commands

So in my creative Minecraft world, I was trying out commands in command blocks. Now redstone is not my thing, so I still don't entirely know how they work. I was putting some `/teleport` commands in there and going to different places around the world. But for some reason, if I try to have more than one command block in my world with another `/teleport` command, it doesn't work. For example, I put `[/tp @p 167 97 91]` in a command block and it worked. I did teleport to where I wanted to go. I tried to do another one, this time going to a different place. I had another command block with the command `[/tp @p 70 71 -48]` and placed a pressure plate on it. It did not work. I did not go anywhere. I'm not sure why this is happening, and I hope someone else can help.

Comment: can you do me a favor and tell us what the command block's "Previous Output" section is telling you, ie. is there any error that's popping up?

Comment: Flagging question as unclear because it lacks enough information to determine which edition is being played.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need redstone for command blocks at all. What you need to do depends on your situation, but if it should executed every tick for example, you can set it to "repeating". - [Fabian Röling](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/171580/fabian-r%C3%B6ling) in a [comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/348230/i-cant-have-more-than-one-working-command-block-in-my-minecraft-world#comment489981_348230)